# php ajax pagination getting data from another domain

Tags: php, pagination, cross-domain

So, i have a site that grabs data from another one of my sites and displays it accordingly. Things are starting to slow down as there is now a lot of data and the query i have grabs all results. So its time to implement some pagination.

Here is my jQuery to grab the data:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
        var ID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        jQuery('.show_more').hide();
        jQuery('.loding').show();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            async: true,
                        crossDomain : true,
            url:'http://example.com/retailers/products.php?apikey=123456&retailer=Test',
            data:'id='+ID,
            success:function(html){
                jQuery('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
                jQuery('.retailitems').append(html);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

With the above i get the following error:

```
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I know i can use `datatype: jsonp` but is there an alternative i can use, as i own the other domain? Is there something i can setup on the other domain to allow this?

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: You can use htaccess file to remove this error at other domain from where you are grabbing data

Comment: Thats exactly what im trying to do... just trying to solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Add `.htaccess` file at the root folder to remove the cross origin issue on the domain from where you are getting data..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that this works, placing it at the top of the requested file:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```